# Find index in sorted list in constant time

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a set of custom objects I'm adding to a list and then sorting with a custom comparator. I then have a second list of some subset of these objects which I need the index of in the first list so that I can find the objects which are equal (as defined by my comparator). As the list is sorted these objects should simply be the objects directly before or after this object, but I don't know beforehand how many will be the same (likely 2-3).

I need this lookup to be in constant time as my list of sorted objects will be quite large. I could obviously just use list.index(), but that will be O(N) and I think I can do better. My first thought was to use a doubly linked list, but it looks like I would need to implement that myself and I'm not exactly sure how I would sort it.

Is there a double linked list implementation in python? Or is there a better alternative to this problem? Also, I'm currently on python2.5 and can't update my version, but if I'm limited by my version I'm still interested in hearing about that solution.

Comment: I think constant time is not possible if you don't have another property which allows computation (like in `range`). However you can always use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) if `O(log n)` is enough.

Comment: I think it should be possible to get a constant time lookup if I do a O(N) setup after my sort. At the very least I could iterate through the list and add the object's index to each object which could be referenced when I pull the object out of my second list.

That solution seems like a bit of a hack as I assume there should be a way for a list implementation to handle this for me, but I do think it would likely work.

Comment: For the price of additional O(N) storage, you might create a dictionary to back the list indices of the sorted list: `dict((e,i) for (i,e) in enumerate(sorted_list))`.  This would give you O(1) lookup for the position of items in your second list.

Comment: @wildwilhelm Depends on how the items implement equality (and what the custom comparator does). Remember that dictionaries treat keys as equal if and only if they are equal (`obj1 == obj2`) and their hashes are equal (`hash(obj1) == hash(obj2)`).

Comment: I vote for using the `bisect` module. There is no way to achieve constant time lookup with what I understand from your problem. Using a double linked list would be worse than an ordinary list (By the way there is a double linked list implementation in the standard library: `collection.deque`).

Comment: @MSeifert absolutely!  The backing `dict` approach relies on the objects having `__eq__` defined properly, and also being hashable.

Comment: Also note that the search functions in the bisect module accept parameters to specify minimum and maximum index, so that you can use the fact that your second list is sorted.

Comment: I believe @wildwilhelm's solution using a dict provides what I'm looking for.  
My objects are fairly simple, basically just a float with a few other parameters, and I should only have on the order of 10k of them.

Comment: @wildwilhelm Your answer worked perfectly for me. Testing with a 10k entries my application's runtime using the dict was under 2 seconds while using basic list lookups it was taking on the order of 10+ minutes.

If you post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the price of additional O(N) storage, you might create a dictionary to back the list indices of the sorted list:

```
index_map = dict((e,i) for (i,e) in enumerate(sorted_list))
```

This would give you O(1) lookup for the position of items in your second list.

If the elements of `sorted_list` are custom objects, then, as @mseifert points out, this approach relies on the objects having `__eq__` defined properly, and also being hashable.

Comment: note, `{e: i for i, e in enumerate(sorted_list)}` is some nice syntactic sugar

Comment: ...or, for that matter, `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted_list)))`. Not very sugary but might tickle the FP folks.